# Angularjs- Issue with updating $scope in the callback of $resource delete method (thinkster.io 3rd chapter)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a controller in AngularJS as following (according to the 3rd chapter of the angularjs tutorial on thinkster.io: http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/S2MxGFCO0B/3-communicating-with-a-server-using-a-service-and-resource)

`posts.js`

```
app.controller('postCtrl', function ($scope, Post) {

  $scope.posts = Post.get();
  $scope.post = { url: 'http://', title: '' };

  $scope.submitPost = function () {
    ...
  };

  $scope.deletePost = function (postId) {
    Post.delete({ id: postId }, function () {
      delete $scope.posts[postId];
      console.log($scope.posts);
    });
  };

});
```

`post.js`

```
app.factory('Post', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('https://luminous-heat-3725.firebaseIO.com/posts/:id.json');
});
```

`posts.html`

```
<div ng-repeat="(postId,post) in posts">
  <a href="{{post.url}}">{{post.title}}</a>
  <a href="#" ng-click="deletePost(postId);">Delete</a>
</div>
```

It's a simple controller - with a function to submit posts and a function to delete posts.

The problem I am facing is that the callback in the deletePost function does not seem to work. 
So, the line `delete $scope.posts[postId]` seems to work initially and the `console.log($scope.posts)` gives the correct output (with the post deleted).

But the DOM does not get updated (the post still shows). 
If I look at the scope in the AngularJS debugger in Chrome, the post that I deleted is still present.
I have to refresh in order to see the post deletion in the DOM.
`$scope.$apply()` did not seem to work as well.

I spent a lot of time and figured this has something to do with the scope of the $scope variable. So I came to the following solution:
I set window.obj to be equal to $scope and then used window.obj instead of scope in the deletePost function.

Like this:

```
window.obj = $scope;
$scope.deletePost = function (postId) {
  Post.delete({ id: postId },function () {
    delete window.obj.posts[postId];
  });
};
```

It works now.
Can anyone explain why I have to set a global variable for this?
Am I making a mistake of some kind?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Post.delete` is deleting the resource in the server, but that is independent of the current model (`$scope.posts`). If you want to update it too, you can call `$scope.posts.splice(postId, 1)`.

Comment: Isn't that what the `delete $scope.posts[postId];` in the callback does? (posts is a json object and not an array)  When I console.log($scope.posts) in the callback, I can see that the post DID get deleted. But somehow that does not reflect in the DOM

Comment: Then I can't figure out where is the problem. I have tried to reproduce your problem, but it looks like it works as expected: http://plnkr.co/edit/x0rS3I2HSWh49ieGCV2P?p=preview.

Comment: Found the bug: I was needlessly including ngSanitize as a dependency for my module. When I removed it, the app started working. On further inspection, my angular-sanitize.js file was incomplete. Replaced the file and everything OK now - even with the ngSanitize dependency. Thanks :)